# The passage of Eternity

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

This is it! You've finally found it: The Passage of Eternity!

You've been looking for this mythical Passage for years, but now you've finally found it. All that's left is to unravel its long hidden secret.
To your surprise it came with a small box that looks like it needs a password. No matter, now to read the Passage:

> I'm sure you're on cloud nine finding a double eight page.
> Trash her unfortunately, but some just disappoint.
> Alternatively, you did work your teeth plenty to get your hat far...
> Last time truth's page was found, tough sobs gave up.
> Largely, truth would be quite confusing.
> Bad problem keeping you awake?
> Even if you try to burn a mouse, diddly-squat will ensue.
> Given plenty of musk it isn't possible to surpass a test.
> I could only sum two if I want to, you will give up like everyone else.
> Never believe your luck will solve Eternity, it is a silly superstition.
> Save your air, it is ad hoc for an aim, test's conundrum HR keeps you, and your time.
> Will you die, or leave and live, is it sacrosanct to you?
> I suppose I'll be unable to use launchd  on your brain to give up?
> This requires bath soap and a wishbone to grace you with anguish never ending until you do!
> Have an eternal twitch, not arm chaff!
>
> May the passage ever be against you.

What's that supposed to mean?

Comment: I'm mostly just amazed that an ancient mystical passage would reference `launchd` :P

Comment: @CaptainPlanet Prophets

Comment: Does this puzzle require trivia knowledge? The last line especially seems to reference rot13 the (Uhatre Tnzrf)

Comment: No trivia is needed here. I would've placed the trivia tag if that were the case as it doesn't really reveal anything about the puzzle. If it comes down to it I'll swap out the enigmatic tag for another one. (I used enigmatic to obfuscate the solution else it would've been solved incredibly fast)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The password is

> **BANANA**

As Joe-You-Know pointed out,

> the first letter of each line spells out "IT ALL BEGINS WITH M".

If you then

> look at the letters after each **M** in the text, they spell out
>  **seekoutthec**, which is obviously meant to say, "Seek out the **C**".

Continuing on in the same pattern,

> the letters after each **C** in the text spell out
>  **lookforthehh**, which I interpret as "Look for the **H**".

And one more time,

> the letters after each **H** spell out
>  **thepasswordisbanana**, or "The password is **BANANA**".

Comment: I think you nailed this on the head. I never would have figured out what the first clue was talking about. +1

Comment: This is correct :) good job.

Answer (score 3):

**Partial Answer**
Well, the first letter of each line reads

> IT ALL BEGINS WITH M (thanks to Rand Al'Thor for pointing this out and that it's not "I tall begins with M")

So I think the password may be

> The letter M

I'm not sure what the other lines refer to though

Comment: *it all* seems more likely than *I tall* ...

Comment: You know, that makes a lot more sense now...

Comment: There's more to it than that. That's a good start though.